# Under which conditions does electric field not vanish inside a conductor?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

As the title explains, there's a conceptual question in an exam that I could not figure out. Under which conditions $\vec{E} \neq 0$ in a conductor? In addition, I'm also asked to give an example of such situation, so I would be pleased if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why are certain fields repelled from the bulk of a conductor?

To cancel the external electric field inside of a conductor, charges need to build up on the surface of a conductor. These charges "sink" the incoming electric field lines via Gauss's law. If not enough charge is able to be built up, electric field lines leak in, and induce a drift current in the bulk.

To cancel an external changing magnetic field in a conductor, eddy currents establish themselves on the surface of a conductor. These currents produce magnetic field lines that oppose the changing magnetic field. If the changing magnetic field leaks in, by Faraday's law, a swirling electric field can enter the bulk and induce further eddy currents there.

### How can we partially overcome these effects for a period of time?

An electrical circuit powered by a battery induces the first situation by constantly pulling charge from one terminal to another, so electric charge does not fully build up on certain conductor surfaces in the circuit. Because a conductor has finite conductance, electric field remains in the conductor and causes electrons to drift.

The scenario of eddy electric fields and currents can be induced by exposing a conductor to a changing magnetic field. Because a conductor has finite conductance, charges cannot swirl fast enough to cancel all of the incoming changing magnetic field lines.

You can read up on "electromotive forces" for more details.

Comment: Now that you mention this, I remember I saw such a situation while studying Faraday's Law of Induction.Thank you!